# None of my windows machines can connect to my wifi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Recently, an old PC (Windows 10) of mine that has been connecting to the same wifi network for over 6 years without issue has suddenly become completely unable to do so.

- I click Connect
- It says "checking network requirements", then after a few seconds asks me to "enter the network security key"
- I do so, click Next.
- "Checking network requirements"
- "Can't connect to this network"

No explanation, no help.

I reset the router, and thinking there was something wrong PC-side I uninstalled and reinstalled the network adapter including drivers, no luck.

I tried connecting from a different (brand new) Windows 10 machine and that one was also unable to connect (same exact process outlined above), even though I have a Mac and numerous mobile devices connecting without issue.

I haven't changed anything on the router as far as I know. The password is the same too.

Why is this only affecting my Windows 10 machines?

Comment: There may be a compatibility issue with the wireless router. I would try a different router to see. Perhaps you could borrow a router.

Comment: 1. Try the PC using another WiFi source, e.g., public library. 2. Check your router settings to see if connection by older protocols, e.g., Legacy 802.12, has been disabled.